# Geometry does not seem to change the margins

Tags: geometry

I am trying to change the margins of my document with geometry. It seems not work.

this is my preamble

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[paper=a4paper,showframe=true, left=10mm,right=10mm,top=10mm,bottom=10mm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[default]{lato}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{hyperref} % Required for adding links   and customizing them
\hypersetup{colorlinks, breaklinks, urlcolor=Gray, linkcolor=Gray} % Set link colors
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{text}{HTML}{2b2b2b} % The primary document color for content text
\definecolor{headings}{HTML}{A901DB}
\definecolor{subheadings}{HTML}{333333} % The color of subsections and places worked/studied
\definecolor{name}{HTML}{6A6A6A} % The color of the large sections
\color{text}

\newlength{\datebox}\settowidth{\datebox}{1234567891011} % Set the width of the date box in each block

\newcommand{\NewEntry}[3]{\noindent\hangindent=0em\hangafter=0 \parbox{\datebox}{\small \textit{#1}}\hspace{0.2em} #2 #3 % Define a command for each new block - change spacing and font sizes here: #1 is the left margin, #2 is the italic date field and #3 is the position/employer/location field
\vspace{0.5em}} % Add some white space after each new entry

\newcommand{\Contacts}[3]{\noindent\hangindent=0em\hangafter=0 \parbox{\datebox}{\small \textit{#1}}\hspace{-0.5em} #2 #3 % Define a command for each new block - change spacing and font sizes here: #1 is the left margin, #2 is the italic date field and #3 is the position/employer/location field
\vspace{0.5em}} % Add some white space after each new entry

\newcommand{\Description}[1]{\hangindent=0em\hangafter=0\noindent\raggedright\footnotesize{#1}\par\normalsize\vspace{1em}} % Define a command for descriptions of each entry - change spacing and font sizes here

\newcommand{\Jobs}[1]{\hangindent=0em\hangafter=0\noindent\raggedright\footnotesize{#1}\par\normalsize\vspace{.5em}} 


\newcommand{\Pub}[1]{\hangindent=0em\hangafter=0\noindent\raggedright\footnotesize{#1}\par\normalsize\vspace{1em}} % Define a command for descriptions of each entry - change spacing and font sizes here


\newcommand{\Titlename}[1]{\centering{\textcolor{subheadings}{\fontseries{l}\fontsize{40}{60}\selectfont #1}}}

\newcommand{\Goal}[1]{\flushright{\textcolor{subheadings}{\fontsize{10}{15}\selectfont #1}}}
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. In particular, please note that you should complete your code to create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). That is, you should post a complete, small document we can copy-paste-compile to reproduce the problem.

Comment: The `geometry` package does work. :-) It's just that you subsequently load `classicthesis`, which has its own page setting ideas.

Comment: Off-topic: `\footnotesize`, `\centering` don't take an argument. They are switches. On-topic: `classicthesis` uses `typearea` so you should use it to configure page layout dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

One of the main goals of the `classicthesis` template is to provide a typographically pleasing document. No matter how buggy the implementation is.
The manual begs the user not to change the margins.

Nvertheless, if you want to change the margins to specified values, the recommended way with KOMA-script is to use package `geometry` indeed. But *after* loading `classicthesis`.

As [cfr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/39222/cfr) notes in the comments, neither `\footnotesize` nor `centering` do take any argument.